# <Mathematical Statistics> Confused by the idea of distribution of a random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am self-learning mathematical statistics for my undergraduate statistics course, and I am confused by this concept of "distribution of a random variable".

The reference that I am using is this one: http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/mikevans/jeffrosenthal/

I will briefly state what I think I understand right now, and also state what my confusion is in the following:

Maybe Understand:

1. The idea of what a random variable is. It's just a function assigning each outcome in sample space to a real number in $R^1$ [Although I am indeed curious if this random variable can only be assigned to a subset of $R^1$, would this still make it a random variable? Like X = x, but Z = $\sqrt{X}$, is Z still a random variable?]
2. Any constant is a random variable since we can just define c(s) = c.
3. Indicator functions $I_B(s)$.

4.The distribution of a random variable. From its definition I intuitively understand it's a collection of probabilities of all possible values of random variable. It looks something like P(x $\in$ B) = 0.3$I_B(3)$ + 0.4$I_B(4)$ [Just some random expression that I made up

I don't understand or am confused about:

1. Some examples shown in the reference says that you can do something like S = {rainy, sunny, snowy}, X(rainy)=30, X(sunny) = 40, X(snowy) = -20, and assign their probability like P(X=rainy)=0.3, P(X=sunny)=0.4, P(X=snowy)=0.3. I don't understand why this kind of "randomly assign probability" is allowed.
2. What does the value or output of a random variable represent? I mean sometimes its value seems that it comes out of nowhere, and has no connection to the sample space itself. For example, this question is an exercise in section 2.2. It states that:

   Roll 1 six-sided dice, let Z = number that appears on the dice, W = $Z^3 + 4$, do the following: (a) Calculate P(W=w) for w $\in$ R.

I calculated the value for W and conclude that W can be either one of 5, 12, 31, 68, 129, or 200. The only number that appears in this list, which I think it has some connection to sample space itself, is 5, besides 5, like 12 or 31, I don't see any connection to the sample space, which force me to conclude that P(W=5) = $\frac{1}{6}$, and any other value besides 5 has probability of 0.

To summarize, I need some help understanding:

1. the meaning of output of a random variable
2. what is the connection between each output of a random variable to a specific probability in the sample space.

Comment: $P(W=12)=1/6=P(W=31)=P(W=68)=P(W=129)=P(W=200)$. $P(Z=1)=1/6$ etc. $W$ and $Z$ are different random variables. If you want a simple interpretation, imagine a game where you roll a die and your score is $4$ plus the cube of your roll. Then $Z$ is what you rolled and $W$ is your score.

Comment: So it's like P(W(Z=1)) = P(Z=1) = $|frac{1}{6}$? We just solely look at the value of z since w is dependent on z? I am not sure if I understand this correct, I have been thinking random variable is some kind of "numerical event" that sample space is constructed of, in other words, I think S has to satisfy some properties that random variables are claiming of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, a random variable is just a number that depends on the outcome of some experiment.  It can be quite natural: "Measure the current temperature and record the outcome in degrees."  Or it can be arbitrary: "Toss a coin.  You get $10$ points if it comes up heads and $-15$ points if it comes up tails."  The strange examples is the text are just intended to illustrate that no assumption is being made about the function, except that it is real-valued.  If $X$ is a random variable, the so is any function of $X$.  (The last two sentences apply to finite probability spaces.  On an infinite probability space, there are some modest technical requirements.)

The "randomly assigned probability" that confuses you is just an example in the book.  Imagine that the probabilities of having those kinds of weather are as given.

The value of a random variable and the probabilities in the space have no connection whatsoever.  I don't really see where this question is coming from.

The distribution of random variable $X$ is $$F(x)=\Pr(X<x)$$  It is a function, not a collection of probabilities.  You may be thinking of a probability mass function, which on a finite probability space, is the function that assigns to each possible value of a random variable $X$, the probability that $X$ assumes that value.  For example, let $X$ be the sum of the faces when two fair dice are rolled.  Then $$\Pr(X=2)={1\over36}\\\Pr(X=3)={2\over36}
$$ 
If $F$ is the distribution function of $X$ then $$F(3)={3\over36}$$